# Typescript error TS2449: Class 'x' used before its declaration, and insure that 'X' is declared here

Tags: typescript, dto, tsc

Such this question is asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680616/typescript-error-ts2449-class-x-used-before-its-declaration) and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810255/class-x-used-before-its-declaration)
but it can't help. my case is different.

I have one typescript file containing 40 DTO class converted from C# file, like:

```
//model.ts

export class A extends B
{
//...
}

export class B
{
//...
}

export class C
{
//...
}
export class D extends C
{
//...
}

//more classes

}
```

When I try to compile the file using tsc I get an error:

```
model.ts:3:24 - error TS2449: Class 'B' used before its declaration.
3 export class A extends B
                         ~
  model.ts:8:14
    8 export class B
                   ~
    'B' is declared here.
```

If I Generated the c# class as  interface, compilation success without error.
tsc say that class B is declared here, but can't use it.

Sure, editing the file and moving the B class before A class, I get no error.

I want to avoid the manual editing of the converted file.

My Question:
Is there an option in tsc configuration or other way  to avoid this error and the manual editing of the generated file?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You can't create class A that extends class B before B has been declared. Think about it - how can you extend something that doesn't exist yet? If you change your code to declare B and *then* declare A as extending B, it makes sense and will work.

Comment: I said the file is converted from c# file (not my code). I simplified the case. in c# it doesn't mater the order of the class child can be before parent.

Comment: How do you convert it? It seems like the converter doesn't work correctly.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that C# accepts it that way, but that's also irrelevant. It doesn't work that way in Typescript, apparently.

Comment: Tsc handle the compilation of  class in a different way than interface. If the file is interfaces only (and child is before parent/base class, no such errors are fired.

Comment: Maybe a stupid approach but just so I suggested it - splitting it in seperate files so the bundler has to take them in correct order. (probably can't tell the generator to do that but still the only thing I can get up with right now)

Comment: What generator is this?

Comment: @caTs, I find a good tool that reorder the classes based on the dependency. I test it and the error disappear. it's CSharp2TS

Comment: Well, if it solves your problem, might as well answer your own question.

Comment: @KenWhite: Modern compilers have done a loooong way so it's nothing strange that languages like C# and others also allow top-down declarations, instead of bottom-up. The only thing that matters is that everything can be resolved at compile time. Being JS JIT compiled, they probably preferred a syntax that can resolve type shape quicker. Actually it's a shame they didn't relax this enforcement in TS, though. I also organize my source files in a top-down style for readability (super classes tend to be what one uses most), so I think you may review what you think makes sense and what not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a good tool that reorder the classes based on the dependency, so parent (base class) is written before the child.

It's [csharp2ts](https://github.com/RafaelSalguero/CSharp2TS) by [@Rafael Salguero Iturrios](https://github.com/RafaelSalguero), and it's an extension to VScode.

I converted the c# file and the error disappear